# CSS page-break-after: always; not working in chrome

Tags: pdf, printing, css, print-to-pdf

I am using react-to-print to get the PDF view of the component.
I want to apply pagebreak after and before certain div tags
I used classes to apply the page break but it is not helping
My code

```
@media print {
  h4.red-head
  {
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.
Regards [Mayur](http://cuttingchai.info)